# linear algebra generating set $p_3 = {p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to find the generating set of  $p_3 = {p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3}$

$p(1) = 0 $ and $p(-1) = 0$  then

$p(1) = a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = 0$

$p(-1) = a_0 + -a_1 + a_2 + -a_3 = 0$

To be honest, I'm stuck there. I get the answer from the book, but I don't know how to get it.

Basically, from the book

$a_1 = - a_3$

$a_0 = - a_2$

Then $p(x) = -a_2 -a_3x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3$

$p(x) = a_2(-1 + x^2) + a_3(-x + x^3)$

$(-1 + x^2) $ and $(-x + x^3)$

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Add $a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3=0$ and $a_0-a_1+a_2-a+3=0$ to get $2(a_0+a_2)=0$, and subtract those equations to get $2(a_1+a_3)=0$

Comment: Why I have to add then subtract those equations? 

I don't see how to get $a_1 = -a_3$ from $2(a_0 + a_2) = 0$ and $2(a_1 + a_3)$

Comment: forget the second question, I was dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3=0\tag1$$ and $$a_0-a_1+a_2-a_3=0\tag2.$$

Add $(1)$ and $(2)$ to get $$2(a_0+a_2)=0\implies a_0+a_2=0\implies a_0=-a_2,$$

and subtract $(2)$ from $(1)$ to get $$2(a_1+a_3)=0\implies a_1+a_3=0\implies a_1=-a_3.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

No need to solve the system of linear equations. Here is a quick method.

Basically, the question asks you to find a basis for a subspace of $P_4(F)$. Without any restriction, you know that $(1, x, x^2, x^3)$ is a basis because the general expression is $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$. Now, the given condition implies that $1$ and $-1$ are two roots. Thus, the general expression should be $(x-1)(x+1)(ax+b)$. From here, you should be able to see that one basis is $((x-1)(x+1), (x-1)(x+1)x)$ right away.